# iOS - Segue with variable source / destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that will itself be `subclassed` into many custom `UIViewControllers`. It contains a method to check authentication info, and if the authentication fails, it should `segue` to a particular `view`. I am looking at making use of `UIStoryboardSegue's *"segueWithIdentifier"*` method for this purpose. The question is, what do I specify for the `destination` parameter, i.e. how do I get the `UIViewController` instance pertaining to my desired `destinationviewcontroller`?

Comment: add your storyboard pic in your question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I afraid it's not that easy because ever subclass of your view controller could go to different view controller and if you want to do it via segue all of that segue will be different. I think the best solution is let your child view controller decide which segue to fire (which view present/push). 
Add your check authentication method like that to the parent view controller

```
-(void)checkAuthentication
{
    if (userAuthenticated)
    {
        [self userAuthenticatedMethod];
    }
    else
    {
         // if you want to go to the same view controller if user not authenticated you can
         // perfoem segue like that: 
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"failedSegue" sender:nil];
         // but if it depends on the view controller you are in do it like that
         [self userNotAuthenticatedMethod];
    }
}
```

Add declaration of this method to .h file and put empty implementation to .m file:

```
//in .h
-(void)userAuthenticatedMethod;
//just if you need it
//-(void)userNotAuthenticatedMethod;

//in .m
-(void)userAuthenticatedMethod
{
    //override in child
}
//just if you need it
//-(void)userNotAuthenticatedMethod
{
    //override in child
}
```

Now in every child view controller you need to implement userAuthenticatedMethod method and if needed userNotAuthenticatedMethod.
If you want to use segue just do something like that:

```
-(void)userAuthenticatedMethod
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

You can also add view controller to view hierarchy programatically. In this scenario each child view controller is responsible to add another view to the view hierarchy.
If you need pass the data you can override prepareForSegue: method in every child VC you want.